# Pandas Datareader: Why do I get Type Error

Tags: typeerror, pandas-datareader

import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2020,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2021,1,1)

web.DataReader('GOOGL','yahoo',start,end)

---

What is wrong with this code ? Why am I getting this error ?

TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: string indices must be integers

I was expecting to extract the data from Yahoo Finance